# Get std::fstream failure error messages and/or exceptions

Tags: c++

I'm using fstream. Is there any way to get the failure message/exception?

For example if I'm unable to open the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From checking it out I found that also `errno` and also `GetLastError()` do set the last error and checking them is quite helpful. For getting the string message use:

```
strerror(errno);
```

Comment: It would be great if you supplied some code snippets on how you used this functions

Comment: GetLastError() is Windows only.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror

Answer (score 32):

Streams by default do not throw exceptions on error, they set flags. You can make them throw exceptions by using the stream's exception() member function:

```
ifstream ifs;
ifs.exceptions( std::ios::failbit );   // throw if failbit get set
```

Theoretically, you could then do something like this:

```
try {
  int x;
  ifs >> x;
}
catch( const std::exception & ex ) {
   std::cerr << "Could not convert to int - reason is " 
                  << ex.what();
}
```

Unfortunately, the C++ Standard does not specify that thrown exceptions contain any error message, so you are in implementation specific territory here.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: no. Even checking `errno` after you detect failure (using e.g. `bad()`, `fail()`) after various operations doesn't reliably work. Creating an `ifstream`/`ofstream` wrapping a file that can't be opened doesn't necessarily set a failure bit until you try to read, write, or close it.

Long answer: you can call `ios::exceptions(ios_base::iostate)` to request that `ios_base::ios_failure` exceptions be thrown when a corresponding bit (badbit, failbit, eofbit) is set, but this (at least on GNU and Microsoft C++ libraries) doesn't get you any more information than manually checking the bits, and ends up being largely pointless, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a more detailed message than what is provided by [`std::ios_base::failure`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) then here is an example which uses [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) to *re-raise* a [`std::system_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error):

```txt
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  broken/path: No such file or directory
```

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  const std::string filename{ "broken/path" };
  try {
    std::ifstream file{ filename };
    file.exceptions(std::ios::failbit); // std::ios_base_failure is thrown here
  } catch (std::ios_base::failure&) {
    throw std::system_error{ errno, std::generic_category(), filename };
  }
}
```

This works on UNIX and Windows because "All `errno` values are … UNIX-compatible" ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-doserrno-sys-errlist-and-sys-nerr?view=msvc-160)).

If you want *even-more-specific* Windows error codes (i.e. *file is already open in another program*), you should look to the platform-specific `GetLastError()` api instead of `errno`.