# write to a file

Tags: c++

I want to write to a file named "TEXT" and append to the file every time I run the program. It compiles but it does not take input. Please help out; I am new to programming.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

main ()
{
    string line;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("TEXT",ios::in |ios::app);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (file.good() )
        {
            getline (file,line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    } else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

Comment: If you want to write to the file, then why do you open it for input and read from it?

Comment: This code is so far away from what you want, you might as well start from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what you want to do but here's some basic input/output operations on a text file. Hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream input("TEXT", ios::in); // Opens "TEXT" for reading

    if(input.fail()) 
    {
       cout << "Input error: could not open " << "TEXT" << endl;
       exit(-1);
    }


    while(getline(input, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl; // prints contents of "TEXT"
    }

    input.close(); // close the file

    ofstream output("TEXT", ios::app); // opens "TEXT" for writing
    if(output.fail()) 
    {
       cout << "Output error: could not open " << "TEXT" << endl;
       exit(-1);
    }

    output << "I am adding this line to TEXT" << endl; // write a line to text
    output.close(); // close the file

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To write to the file rather than reading from it, you basically need to change the type of `file` to an output stream (`ofstream`), `file` to `cin` and `cout` to `file`. You can also simplify a few things. A stream will automatically convert to a true value if the next operation will succeed, and a false one if it will fail, so you can test a stream simply by referring to it. There's nothing wrong with (e.g.) `while (file.good())`, it's just not as idiomatic as `while (file)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cerrno>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line;
    string fname="TEXT";
    /* You can open a file when you declare an ofstream. The path
       must be specified as a char* and not a string.[1]
     */
    ofstream fout(fname.c_str(), ios::app);

    // equivalent to "if (!fout.fail())"
    if (fout) {
        while (cin) {
            getline(cin,line);
            fout << line << endl;
        }
        fout.close();
    } else {
        /* Note: errno won't necessarily hold the file open failure cause
           under some compilers [2], but there isn't a more standard way
           of getting the reason for failure.
         */
        cout << "Unable to open file \"" << fname << "\": " << strerror(errno);
    }
}
```

References:

1. [Why don't the std::fstream classes take a std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332/why-dont-the-stdfstream-classes-take-a-stdstring)
2. [Get std::fstream failure error messages and/or exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839644/get-stdfstream-failure-error-messages-and-or-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

This program successfully opens "TEXT" for reading and print its content to stdout...

---

If you want to read from input, you need to `readline` from `stdin`:

```
getline( cin, line );
```

instead of

```
getline (file,line);
```

Then you will need to open `file` for writing (using `ios::out` flag instead of `ios::in`, and without `ios::app`) and write in there instead than in `stdout`:

```
file << line << endl;
```

instead of

```
cout << line << endl;
```

Comment: can you pls make the change in the code...when i run this it is not taking the input...