# Accessing specific lines of text file c++

Tags: c++

I want to access specific lines in of text file to display or modify that one. My text file contains lines of different lengths and i heard cannot use seekg or seekp for such files. I got a code but it doesn't works. Can someone please tell me its fault of some other helpful idea?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num)
{
    file.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i < num - 1; ++i)
    {
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
    }
    return file;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num);
    cout << "Starting..." << endl;
    fstream file("bla.txt");
    GotoLine(file, 8);
    string line8;
    file >> line8;
    cout << "[" << line8 << "]" << endl;
    // cin.get();
    cout << "Finished..." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Helpful idea 1: step through the code with debugger... Think what next line should do, then hit "step" in debugger, then see what it actually did.

Comment: Helpful idea 2: when asking for help from somebody else, "it doesn't works" is not very descriptive. You should tell what the code does/how it behaves, and how it is different from what it should do/how it should behave.

Comment: Helpful idea 3: when using any system or library functions, always check for errors, and (for example) print an error message if error happens (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839644/get-stdfstream-failure-error-messages-and-or-exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string line8;
file >> line8;
```

will only extract until the first whitespace character is hit.

you could use something like:

```
string line8;
getline(file, line8);
```

This at least worked for me with the rest of your code on Windows 7 with VS2012

Answer (score 1):

Standard [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (and earlier versions of the standard) dont have notion of lines contained inside files. Also [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) (and even Windows or MacOSX) don't have it. Textual files usually contain lines of variable length (and only the line terminator is relevant, either `\n` or `\r\n` or `\n\r`, depending upon the operating system and perhaps the file read mode -binary or textual-).

<sup>In the 1960s or 1970s IBM mainframe [OS/360](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/360_and_successors) operating systems had "file" systems which did have files made of fixed-length lines, mimicking punched cards.</sup>

So, you have to read your file line by line and remember where are the line limits (or use [std::istream::ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to skip till `\n`).
Alternatively, read every line of your file into a `std::vector<std::string>` using [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) on  `std::ifstream`-s.

For `/etc/fstab`  (or `/proc/mounts`) reading all the lines in a vector is a good idea, since it is always a tiny file. It usually have less than an few dozens of lines, often less than about a hundred char each. The pathological case could be a file with many thousand lines of comments, but that don't really happen in practice.

Comment: Isn't that what `fstream::ignore` does?