# In today's C++, can I reliably get errors when constructing an fstream?

Tags: c++, error-handling, fstream, ifstream, system-error

I want to read from a file using C++ standard library facilities (`std::ifstream`) - while, of course, reliably reporting errors if I encounter them.

Apparently, this is not at all an easy task!

- [`std::basic_fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream)'s (the template of which `std::ifstream` is an instantiation) do not throw exceptions by default.
- You can make a basic fstream throw exceptions - but only after construction, so the construction won't fail. See [`basic_ios::exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) (that's a super-superclass of `std::ifstream`).

14 years ago, this question was asked:

[Get std::fstream failure error messages and/or exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/839644/1593077)

and the answers tell us that:

1. There are no guarantees the thrown exception will tell us what the cause of the error was (just that some error occurred)
2. We are not guaranteed that when a failbit or badbit  is set on an fstream, `errno` / `GetLastError()` provide us with a non-zero/non-success value.

That's quite bad. On the other hand, 14 years have passed. Has anything changed? That is, are there better guarantees regarding the thrown exception, or of `errno` / `GetLastError()` being set? If not, what is the "best effort" approach to reporting an error in the construction of an `std::fstream`?

(I am tempted to ask "why does the constructor not throw on failure?", but let's not talk about that.)

Comment: I'm not sure why you want constructor throw. afaict you can open the file after default construction.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `is_open()` works the same as it did 14 years ago, and reliably reports a failure to open the file just like it always did.

Comment: @appleapple: Really? It is idiomatic in C++ for a constructor to result in a usable object in a valid state, and when this is not possible, for an error to be thrown.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: `is_open()` gives me a boolean. I need to know what error has occurred.

Comment: @appleapple You could still use the object afterwards by opening a different file or using different flags so ig it'd be still in a usable state.

Comment: @einpoklum yes I didn't say it clearly, I mean I do know why you want it throw. But I don't think throw a exception is a good way here.

Comment: @einpoklum I agree that it'd be nicer if the actual error was provided but you could manually do some checks using `std::filesytem` for file existence, permissions etc.

Comment: @Staz yes, though I'm not sure what part of my comment you're reply to

Comment: @Staz: That can't work, in principle, since the filesystem state may change between my checks and the ifstream construction.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "what error has occured" would get reported in `errno`. It is a safe bet that any error would be an OS-level error, reported in `errno`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: How sure is pretty sure? A 10-upvote answer to the old question says it's not always the case.

Comment: The old question is not asking about file open, but errors in general (only file open "for example"), and the answer is responding in general too. The original error, that set errno, might've occured, but other things have happened that set errno to something else. And I would say that that old answer is wrong.

Comment: @appleapple Sorry my bad, wrong tag.
@einpoklum Fair enough, then ig `errno` would be the only way.

Comment: @Sam In what sense is it wrong?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik in practice errno might always get set but I'm reasonably sure the standard offers no such guarantee, which I think is what the answer is trying to say

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best thing I can think of doing right now - "covering my ass" in case `errno` is somehow not set. At worst I'm wasting some cycles re-throwing in the "unhappy path".

```c++
// TODO: Consider checking errno here
std::filesystem::path file_path = whatever();
std::ifstream file(file_path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
try {
    file.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
} catch (std::ios_base::failure& exception) {
    if (errno == 0) {
        throw;
    }
    throw std::system_error{ errno, std::generic_category(),
        "opening file " + file_path.native());
}
```

Comment: Can file.exceptions throw?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: That's what it's [intended to do](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) actually...

Comment: @Nathan No, I think you (and me) are wrong it will throw.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yep, just saw that.

Comment: IIRC, a caught exception can't be re-thrown by name. IOW, `throw exception;` must be just `throw;` instead. Which means the code would have to look more like this instead: `catch (std::ios_base::failure& exception) { if (errno == 0) throw; throw std::system_error{ errno, ... }; }` or this: `catch (std::ios_base::failure& exception) { if (errno != 0) throw std::system_error{ errno, ... }; throw; }` It is a shame that C++ exceptions don't have a concept of "inner exceptions" like some other languages do, allowing the `failure` to be chained to the `system_error` or vice versa.

Comment: Don't you need to `errno = 0` before the constructor?

Comment: @KamilCuk: That depends on what you can assume about errno before the call. Added a comment.